# Parsing blocks of line comments using MGrammar

Tags: parsing, grammar, mgrammar

How can I parse blocks of line comments with MGrammar?

I want to parse blocks of line comments. Line comments that are next to each should grouped in the MGraph output.

I'm having trouble grouping blocks of line comments together. My current grammar uses "\r\n\r\n" to terminate a block but that will not work in all cases such as at end of file or when I introduce other syntaxes.

Sample input could look like this:

```
/// This is block
/// number one

/// This is block
/// number two
```

My current grammar looks like this:

```
module MyModule
{
    language MyLanguage
    {       
        syntax Main = CommentLineBlock*;

        token CommentContent = !(
                                 '\u000A' // New Line
                                 |'\u000D' // Carriage Return
                                 |'\u0085' // Next Line
                                 |'\u2028' // Line Separator
                                 |'\u2029' // Paragraph Separator
                                );   

        token CommentLine = "///" c:CommentContent* => c;
        syntax CommentLineBlock = (CommentLine)+ "\r\n\r\n";

        interleave Whitespace = " " | "\r" | "\n";   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is, that you interleave all whitespaces - so after parsing the tokens and coming to the lexer, they just "don't exist" anymore.

CommentLineBlock is `syntax` in your case, but you need the comment-blocks to be completely consumed in `tokens`...

```
language MyLanguage
{       
    syntax Main = CommentLineBlock*;

    token LineBreak = '\u000D\u000A'
                         | '\u000A' // New Line
                         |'\u000D' // Carriage Return
                         |'\u0085' // Next Line
                         |'\u2028' // Line Separator
                         |'\u2029' // Paragraph Separator
                        ;  

    token CommentContent = !(
                             '\u000A' // New Line
                             |'\u000D' // Carriage Return
                             |'\u0085' // Next Line
                             |'\u2028' // Line Separator
                             |'\u2029' // Paragraph Separator
                            );   

    token CommentLine = "//" c:CommentContent*;
    token CommentLineBlock = c:(CommentLine LineBreak?)+ => Block {c};

    interleave Whitespace = " " | "\r" | "\n";   
}
```

But then the problem is, that the subtoken-rules in CommentLine won't be processed - you get plain strings parsed.

```
Main[
  [
    Block{
      "/// This is block\r\n/// number one\r\n"
    },
    Block{
      "/// This is block\r\n/// number two"
    }
  ]
]
```

I might try to find a nicer way tonight :-)